# How to know which checkboxes are checked?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am having difficulty determining which checkboxes are checked in my MVC project. Here is how I have my checkboxes setup:

```
<div id='myCheckboxDiv'>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)">Check All
    @foreach (var form in @Model.DetailObject.DoaFormGroupDocuments)
    {
        <br>
        var checkBoxId = "chk" + form.DocumentId;
        @Html.CheckBox(checkBoxId, new { value = form.DocumentId, @checked = true });
        @form.DocumentName;
    }
</div>
```

Essentially I load a page that will display a checkbox with each DoaFormGroupDocument within the DetailObject (could be anywhere from 0-10). What I would like to do is when I click a save button at the bottom of the page, the ID associated with each checkbox (each one being unique) gets saved into a list.

To be clear, I don't really want anything to happen specifically on this page, I need the IDs stored in a list that I can use in other areas (pages), so I guess that means I need the checkbox state to be determined in the controller.

Comment: Your question is not full. You should specify, where exactly do yo want the checboxes state to be determined: in controller (on postback) or on client with javascript.

Comment: Am I allowed to? Yeah. Am I proficient with it? No.

Answer (score 0):

you can read sent data from `Request` in your Action method and `check` if it checked or not(checked `CheckBoxes` sent as on value)

```
var list = new List<bool>();
foreach (var form in DetailObject.DoaFormGroupDocuments)
{
    var checkBoxId = "chk" + form.DocumentId;
    if (Request[checkBoxId] == "on")
        list.Add(true);
    else
        list.Add(false);
}
```

**list** is your `CheckBoxes` status. save as you wish.